# Using sendRedirect - hide parameters

Tags: jsp, redirect, parameters, hide, send

My problem is:
I have a jsp application which play the role of a tunnel to only redirect the process to an externel application after it gets the login from the cookie.
thus, my JSP application doesn't contain any forms.
http://xxxxx:8080/who/app?login=" + userid);
?>
as I told you, xxxxx is a remote host.
When I execute this process, we can see the "userid" in the URL.
My question here how can we hide the login from the url with the configurutaion already described.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Could you show a bit more code?

Comment: <head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Redirection page</title>
</head>
<body>


<%
    String userid = (String) session.getAttribute("hwuser");
    ==============================
     response.sendRedirect("http://lxhv:8180/who/app?login=" + userid %>
</body>
</html>

Comment: As you can see, there is no form. I just extract the login and send it to externel application via the url.

Comment: Do you have control over the remote host that receives the redirect?

Comment: yes, I  have ==> I'm getting the login via: String currentLogin = request.getParameter("login");

Comment: If you want to hide the login, perhaps you could encrypt/decrypt it in that case.